# Time Formatting in Discord.js Results in Wrong Values

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I recently just created an account here because I am seeking assistance concerning on how to format the time in Discord.js.

I am using a command handling system for my bot and I am writing a code for the fortune command with a cooldown, which I'm pasting here:

```
const { Collection } = require('discord.js');

// Create a collection to store users' cooldown and set cooldown time.
const cooldowns = new Collection();
const COOLDOWN_SECONDS = 10; // Replace with desired cooldown time in seconds.

function formatTime(seconds) {
  const hours = Math.floor(seconds / 3600);
  const minutes = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60);
  const remainingSeconds = Math.floor(seconds % 60);

  return `${hours} hours, ${minutes} minutes and ${remainingSeconds} seconds`;
}

module.exports = {
    name: 'fortune',
    description: 'Get your fortune told!',
    callback: (client, interaction) => {
        // Check if the user exists in the cooldown. If so, notify it to the user.
        if (cooldowns.has(interaction.user.id)) {
          const remainingTime = COOLDOWN_SECONDS * 1000 - (cooldowns.get(interaction.user.id) - Date.now() / 1000);
          const formattedTime = formatTime(remainingTime);
          interaction.reply({ content: `Please wait for ${formattedTime} to use this command again.`, ephemeral: true });
        } else {
            // No cooldown. Do something here.
            const fortunes = [
                'You will find love soon.',
                'You will have a great day today.',
                'You will be successful in your career.'
            ];
            const fortune = fortunes[Math.floor(Math.random() * fortunes.length)];
            interaction.reply(fortune);

            // Set cooldown.
            cooldowns.set(interaction.user.id, true);
            setTimeout(() => {
                // Remove the user from the set after the time you specified.
                cooldowns.delete(interaction.user.id);
            }, COOLDOWN_SECONDS * 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I set my cooldown time for 10 seconds for testing. I expected the bot to output:
`Please wait for 0 hours, 0 minutes and 10 seconds to use this command again.`

But it outputted with this:
`Please wait for -471833 hours, -23 minutes and -28 seconds to use this command again.`

Is there any way on how can I format the time to the expected output?

Comment: What does `cooldowns.get(interaction.user.id)` return ?

Comment: `cooldowns.get(interaction.user.id)` is similar to `cooldowns.get(message.author.id)` but done in slash command format, it gets the ID of the user who initiated the command and stores it in the cooldowns collection where it will set the cooldown time for the user

Comment: What I mean is: What does it return? By looking at your code, it should be a timestamp in seconds, a timestamp in the past. Your `formatTime` function works correctly which means that the problem is this calculation `COOLDOWN_SECONDS * 1000 - (cooldowns.get(interaction.user.id) - Date.now() / 1000)` and that will be wrong if `cooldowns.get(interaction.user.id)` doesn't return what I've described.

Comment: I've just noticed this `cooldowns.set(interaction.user.id, true)`. So, that is the problem, your using a `boolean` value to calculate `remainingTime`. Try to use `cooldowns.set(interaction.user.id, (Date.now() / 1000))`

Answer (score 1):

I remember about this documentation that maybe useful for you

```js
<!-- Display the countdown timer in an element -->
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
// Set the date we're counting down to
var countDownDate = new Date("Jan 5, 2024 15:37:25").getTime();

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get today's date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now and the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate - now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h "
  + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

  // If the count down is finished, write some text
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "EXPIRED";
  }
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Feel sorry because it was not the answer for your issue. But hope it will make you feel better.

Reference https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp

Thank you